# Number of ways to distribute ice cream to children.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> A certain school of 10 children is visiting the local ice-cream factory to see how ice-cream is made. After the demonstration, the factory has 15 scoops of vanilla ice-cream and 2 scoops of chocolate ice-cream to distribute to the kids. How many ways can the ice-cream be distributed if each child must receive at least one scoop of ice-cream?

My solution to this is by partitioning the set of ways by the number of chocolate scoop a child will get. Let $C$ be the set of ways to distribute all the ice cream and let $C_1,C_2 \subset C$, where $C_i$ is the set where a child gets $i$ scoops of chocolate ice cream. $C_1 = \ $${10}\choose{2}$$\cdot$${8}\choose{8}$$\cdot$${10}\choose{7}$$=5,400\ ways$, where we must first distribute the 2 scoops of chocolate ice cream to the 10 children (${10}\choose{2}$), then give those who are not given a scoop of chocolate ice cream a scoop of vanilla ice cream (${8}\choose{8}$), and lastly I distribute the remaining 7 vanilla ice cream to all 10 children (${10}\choose{7}$). In the same manner, $C_2 = $${10}\choose{1}$$\cdot$${9}\choose{9}$$\cdot$${10}\choose{6}$ $=2,100$ ways. Hence $C = C_1 + C_2 = 7,500 \ $ ways.

Is this correct?

Comment: Why don't you allow the same kid to get two scoops of chocolate?

Comment: Not correct. What about the case when no one gets choco scoop?

Comment: @YJT You're right, I'll edit that.

Comment: @Koro I think that's not possible since all ice cream must be distributed.

Comment: I don’t see anywhere in the question the requirement that all scoops must be distributed.

Comment: Make the kids run around the factory. The first ones back get their choice. The last kid gets nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options (*assuming all scoops must be distributed*):

**One kid gets both scoops of chocolate** You need to choose the lucky one ($10$) options, then give one vanilla to the rest. You are left with 6 vanilla scoops to give the 10 children. It is equivalent to the number of solutions to $x_1+\ldots+x_{10}=6$ with $x_i\geq 0$, which is ${10+6-1 \choose 10}$.

**Two kids get chocolate** You need to choose the two (${10 \choose 2}$) then give the 8 kids a scope of vanilla. You are left with 7 vanilla to give the 10 children, so the same as above with different numbers.

**Total**
$$10 {15 \choose 10} + {10 \choose 2}{16 \choose 10}$$

Comment: There are 10 children.

Comment: Yes, got confused. Edited.

Comment: I see my mistake, I did not consider if a child gets more than one vanilla ice cream.

Answer (score 1):

Total ways to distribute $15V+2C$ among $10$ kids:
$$
\binom{10-1+15}{15}\binom{10-1+2}{2}
$$
subtract the number of ways one kid gets nothing:
$$
10\times\binom{9-1+15}{15}\binom{9-1+2}{2}
$$
add the number of ways two kids get nothing:
$$
\binom{10}{2}\times\binom{8-1+15}{15}\binom{8-1+2}{2}
$$
and so on. In total:
$$
\binom{10-1+15}{15}\binom{10-1+2}{2}-\sum_{k=1}^{9}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{10-k-1+15}{15}\binom{10-k-1+2}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

First notice that there are two cases for the distribution of $2$ chocolate scoops. Either $2$ of them go to the same child, or they go to $2$ different child.

**$2$ chocolate scoops go to the same child**
There are 10 ways of giving 2 chocolate scoops to the same child. Every child must get one scoop of ice-cream. There are 10 ways of doing it. Therefore, we give every child a scoop of vanilla ice-cream except the one having two chocolate scoops. After this we have $6$ scoops of vanilla ice cream remained. We can distribute it randomly to the $10$ students. Using the [combination with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) formula,
$$10{n+k-1\choose k}=10{10+6-1\choose10}=30030$$

**$2$ chocolate scoops go to the $2$ different child**
In this case, there are ${10\choose2}$ way to distribute the chocolate scoops. Then give every student a scoop of ice-cream except the $2$ students with chocolate scoops, We have $7$ scoops of ice-cream remained. Again with the combination with repetition formula, we have
$${10\choose2}\cdot{10+7-1\choose10} = 8008$$

The answer is thus $30030 +8008 = 38038$.